# jquery datepicker events not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

when i click in jquery  calendar  it display  value  first time and then when  i click another time another value it doesn't work .

```
   <script>
       $(function(){ 
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
       $( ".ui-state-default" ).on('click',function(event){
          alert(event.toElement.outerText); 
        })
     });
   </script>
```

check demo here **http://jsfiddle.net/epHNZ/592**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this,

```
$(function() { 
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepicker").on('click', '.ui-state-default', function(e){
            alert(e.toElement.outerText); 
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/epHNZ/593/)

or

May be above example unsupported in some browsers, in that case use this

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
          var date =$(this).datepicker('getDate');
          alert(date.getDate());
    }
  })
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/epHNZ/595/)**